# Headset shows as audio card but I can't use it

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Linux noob here spent 3 hours yesterday and another 2 today trying to figure this out.

After a restart my Corsair USB headset doesn't show up on the audio settings, but does show up in the ALSAmixer gui as well as OBS. In OBS I can even see that it's detecting inputput but only through ALSA (doesn't show up under pulseaudio).

Here's what I've tried

-[navigating to cat /proc/asound/cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV5ea.png)
but instead of a "cards" directory I have card0 card1 ect. On alsamixer gui I can see that my headset is card1 but in the /asound/card1 file I can't find anything useful

Next I made a backup of the original alsa.conf file
Code:
cp /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf  /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf.original

Then in the file changed these 0's to 1's and restarted

```
 # defaults

  defaults.ctl.card 0
  defaults.pcm.card 0
```

Then restarted alsa with command from below, then restarted the system

```
/etc/init.d/alsa-utils restart
```

Next tried

```
$ sudo alsactl restore
```

which seemed to have worked for a ton of people but did nothing here

Then I uninstalled and reinstalled PulseAudio, still says no card for configuration

Typing
sudo aplay -l
the headset does show up as a card but I still can't find a way to make it work

At this point it feels like i'm more likely to break linux than fix my problem so if anyone could help me out that would be much appreciated

Comment: Good question, good answer!  Welcome to Ubuntu.  Be fearless!

Answer (score 0):

After 8 hours of pain, this was it. I didn't have "pipewire."

```
  ----
{ 0  0 } 
 -----
-     -
-     -
--------
$ sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
$ systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
```